# Why doesn't `forEach.call` iterate over every node with class removal？

Tags: javascript

I'm removing a class in `forEach.call`. For some reason it only calls a single time, as shown below.

```js
var all_active = document.getElementsByClassName("active")
Array.prototype.forEach.call(all_active, function(el) {
  el.classList.remove("active");
  console.log(el.tagName);
});
```

```html
<li class="active dropdown">
  <a>123</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="active">1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

The output is `LI`, whereas I would've expected it to give `LI, A`. Why?

Comment: might be that since you removed it before ,the element/elements tagName is undefiend at this point

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are expecting, or what the problem is. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) is a **live** collection of elements. When you remove the class from the first element, the collection's length is also reduced. Thus the `forEach()` will conclude as it's already handled the correct number of elements.

An ASCII illustration may help:

```
 # On first iteration:      # After first iteration:
┌───────────┬──────────┐   ┌──────────┬──────────┐   
│ NodeList  │ Iterator │   │ NodeList │ Iterator │
├───────────┼──────────┤   ├──────────┼──────────┤
│ li.active │   <──    │   │ a.active │          │
├───────────┼──────────┤   ├──────────┼──────────┤
│ a.active  │          │   │          │    <─    │
└───────────┴──────────┘   └──────────┴──────────┘
```

After the first iteration, the `li` is no longer in the collection because it doesn't match the `"active"` class selector anymore.

---

You can sidestep the problem by turning the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) into an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). The array contents won't change when you modify the nodes, it will still point to the initial set of nodes.

```js
var all_active = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

Array.from(all_active).forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.remove("active");
  console.log(el.tagName);
});
```

```html
<li class="active dropdown">
  <a>123</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="active">1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>1</a>
  </div>
</li>
```